# Is there a way to redefine malloc at link time on Windows?

Tags: c, windows

I would like to replace the default malloc at link time to use a custom malloc. But when I try to redefine malloc in my program, I get this error:

```
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR80.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in test.lib(test.obj)
```

This works perfectly on any Unix, and it works on Windows with most functions, but not with malloc. How can I do this? And what is different with malloc that disallow overriding it?

I know I could replace every call to malloc with my custom malloc, or use a macro to do this, but I would rather not modify every third party library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is really good discussion of how hard this is here:

http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/blog/2008-01-10/patching-the-windows-crt/

<s>Apparently, you need to patch the CRT</s>

Edit: actually, a MS employee gave the technique in the discussion.  You need to move your malloc to a lib, and then link it before the CRT

"he also mentions that if you link your malloc as a lib *before* the CRT (i.e. make sure to turn on ‘ignore default libs’ and explictly include the CRT), you’ll get what you want, and can redistribute this lib without problems."

Comment: In the same discussion it is mentioned that the "lib before the crt" approach does not reliably work with functions like (strdup)

Comment: what about `_CrtSetAllocHook`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy8c7wz5.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends in which order you link the files. I think you need to link your custom function first, then the import library.

Comment: This is correct -- he needs to move the malloc to a lib first, turn on "ignore default libs", and then link to the CRT explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

From version 3.0 Firefox uses a custom allocator (AFAIR jmalloc) -- you could check how they did it. I read that they had some problems with it. You may check this [blog post](http://blog.pavlov.net/2008/01/12/jemalloc-builds/).

Answer (score 1):

What about defining malloc=_custom_malloc in the project makefile.
Than adding a file such as:

```
my_memory.c
#undef malloc
#undef calloc
...
void *_custom_malloc(int size) { return jmalloc(size); }
void *_custom_calloc(int size) { return jcalloc(size); }
...
```