# How to use __malloc_hook?

Tags: c, malloc, glibc

In *GNU C Library Reference Manual*, there is an example program(p.65), But I don't know what the three sentences: 
`__malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook;` 
`old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;` 
`__malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;` 
mean. Especailly the second one, who can explain for me? thanks.

```
static void *
my_malloc_hook (size_t size, const void *caller)
{
    void *result;
    /* Restore all old hooks */
    __malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook;
    __free_hook = old_free_hook;
    /* Call recursively */
    result = malloc (size);
    /* Save underlying hooks */
    old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;
    old_free_hook = __free_hook;
    /* printf might call malloc, so protect it too. */
    printf ("malloc (%u) returns %p\n", (unsigned int) size, result);
    /* Restore our own hooks */
    __malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;
    __free_hook = my_free_hook;
    return result;
}
```

I write a little program to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

/* Prototypes for our hooks.  */
static void my_init_hook(void);
static void *my_malloc_hook(size_t, const void *);

/* Variables to save original hooks. */
static void *(*old_malloc_hook) (size_t, const void *);

/* Override initializing hook from the C library. */
void (*__malloc_initialize_hook) (void) = my_init_hook;

static void my_init_hook(void)
{
    old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;
    __malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;
}

static void *my_malloc_hook(size_t size, const void *caller)
{
    void *result;

    /* Restore all old hooks */
    __malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook;

        printf("1: __malloc_hook = %x  old_malloc_hook = %x\n", __malloc_hook, old_malloc_hook);
    /* Call recursively */
    result = malloc(size);

        printf("2: __malloc_hook = %x  old_malloc_hook = %x\n", __malloc_hook, old_malloc_hook);


    /* Save underlying hooks */
    old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;

        printf("3: __malloc_hook = %x  old_malloc_hook = %x\n", __malloc_hook, old_malloc_hook);
    /* printf() might call malloc(), so protect it too. */
    printf("malloc(%u) called from %p returns %p\n",
           (unsigned int)size, caller, result);

    /* Restore our own hooks */
    __malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;
        printf("4: __malloc_hook = %x  old_malloc_hook = %x\n", __malloc_hook, old_malloc_hook);

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
        char *p;
        p = malloc(10);
        free(p);
        return 0;
}
```

the result of the program is :

```
1: __malloc_hook = 0  old_malloc_hook = 0
2: __malloc_hook = 0  old_malloc_hook = 0
3: __malloc_hook = 0  old_malloc_hook = 0
malloc(10) called from 0xb7797f38 returns 0x932c008
4: __malloc_hook = 804849d  old_malloc_hook = 0
```

but now I have more problems, why `old_malloc_hook` are all 0, in 1,2,3, why `__malloc_hook` are 0? I am really confused. Help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, everything is working exactly as expected and the output is fine.

The variable, `__malloc_hook`, is 0 (or null) probably because the system's default is to *not* have a malloc hook.

As David Schwartz mentioned above, saving the original `__malloc_hook` is important so that it can be restored just before the original `malloc()` is called.  That's the line just below the comment `/* Restore all old hooks */`.  I'm guessing that in this specific case, it's unnecessary, since the original malloc hook is `null`, but to be safe it should be done.

Please rest assured that this code is running just like you want it to.  For now, I would simply let this stew for a while and perhaps a light-bulb will go off and one day, you'll understand it completely.  (Sorry, but that's the best I can do today.)

Comment: "I'm guessing that in this specific case, it's unnecessary, since the original malloc hook is null, but to be safe it should be done." Now I understand, for the case that old_malloc_hook is null, it seems the sentence `old_malloc_hook=__malloc_hook` has no sense, but it's necessary for the case that old_malloc_hook is not null.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why but using old_malloc_hook =__malloc_hook causing crash in the android NDK.

Answer (score 4):

It's documented pretty well in the [manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc_hook.3.html).

1. `old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;`: This saves the current malloc hook in a variable called `old_malloc_hook`. Presumably, we're saving it because we're about to change it.
2. `__malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;`: This changes the current malloc hook to be `my_malloc_hook`.
3. `__malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook;`: The changes the malloc hook back to whatever it was before we changed it, the value we saved in `old_malloc_hook`.

Comment: `result = malloc (size);`: This will change `old_malloc_hook`? If not , why we save it from `__malloc_hook`, because we just set `__malloc_hook` to `old_malloc_hook` ?

Comment: Well, the __malloc_hook manipulations change the internal cogwheels of the malloc() function. result = malloc( size ) calls the malloc function (which again will use whatever malloc hook is currently active).

Comment: @ccsnailpp: We save the old one so we can put it back when we're done. We save it because *we* are going to change it and want to leave things the way we found them so we don't screw up anything else.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Sorry, I don't understand `old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;`. Can you give me an example, if we delete this sentence, what will happen?

Comment: @ccsnailpp: If you remove that, then the old malloc hook won't be saved and this code can't put things back the way it found them when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I think what these answers are missing is the following:

`old_malloc_hook` is `NULL` at the start and then `malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook` makes sure that the hook is disabled and we don't infinitely recurse while calling the actual library function `malloc` inside the function `my_malloc_hook`.