# C++. How to trace memory allocation to .so module in linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

We are in a situation that have a large application and now there is a situation that would need to know which .so module is allocating how much memory. I have no idea here, I was wondering a custom allocator overriding operator new, but that didn't help because I still cannot trace which module is doing to allocation. Replacing new by custom allocator would be terrible amount of work. Does anyone know how can I tell which module is doing how much allocations ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy.

You can hook `malloc`, `free`, `realloc` globally in the application. Corresponding articles on Stackoverflow: [How to use __malloc_hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356958/how-to-use-malloc-hook), [An alternative for the deprecated __malloc_hook functionality of glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803456/an-alternative-for-the-deprecated-malloc-hook-functionality-of-glibc).

You can retrieve a caller address from that hooks using `__builtin_return_address` and compare it with addresses of shared libraries. Maybe you have to examine a deeper frame address to get a proper address in a library, not an address of libc++. Read this Stackoverflow article [__builtin_return_address returns null for index >0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888027/builtin-return-address-returns-null-for-index-0).

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [`LD_PRELOAD` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) to hook `malloc`, `realloc`, `free` etc.  That, combined with the info gleaned from [`boost.stacktrace`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html) would get you most (if not all) of what you need.  Not trivial though.

Comment: that doesn't seem very performant. Is there a way how to preload malloc realloc for each .so module (some different function? )

Comment: Not as far as I know.  At the end f the day there's always going to be *some* performance hit -- you're intercepting calls to malloc etc. and doing extra work around the real call.  As for exactly what that hit is and whether or not it's acceptable...?  Only testing will tell.