# C++ / Windows: HeapAlloc() for contention-free per-thread heaps

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, heap-memory, crt

I have a multithreaded application using `boost::thread`. For performance reasons, I'd like each thread to have an independent heap.

I can create a heap using `HeapCreate()` but am unclear how to hook this up to the CRT library so that `new` and `malloc` allocate memory on the created heap.  How can this be done?

Comment: I want to go deeper than that so that everything including all libraries also use my new heap.  I discovered that _crtheap is a global variable so perhaps not possible to set it on a per-thread basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can this be done?

It can't be done without completely replacing the entire memory allocator. For example the scalable memory manager [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/) does exactly that. But replacing the memory allocator is not for the faint hearted.

If you want to use per-thread heap with `HeapCreate`, and your allocation/deallocation code is reasonably contained, then you could simply call `HeapAlloc` and `HeapFree` explicitly in your thread code.  However, I'd be surprised if this was as fast as the standard CRT allocator which performs well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no safe and documented way to replace CRT heap. Hacks only.

For `new`/`delete` statements you could provide global `operator new()` and `operator delete()` that will allocate/deallocate memory in required heap according to current thread. Thread Local Storage (TLS) is usually used to store thread local heap handle.

For `malloc`/`free` there is no such documented way to replace. Most of hacks are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858592/windows-malloc-replacement-e-g-tcmalloc-and-dynamic-crt-linking).

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a "global operator new", which you can use to check what thread you're in and return memory from the appropiate heap. You'll need to supply your own "global delete" as well, of course.

This will, of course, only "catch" cases where new and delete are actually used :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: use multiple DLLs, each identical in all but name.  Load a different DLL per thread.

Comment: That would require static linking of of the CRT.