# Use jemalloc on windows as like tcmalloc

Tags: c++, winapi, jemalloc

I want to use `jemalloc` on windows as like `tcmalloc`. In `tcmalloc` I just need to include the `tcmalloc` header in source and link with `tcmalloc_minimal.lib` and Force include `__tcmalloc` symbol in linker option. All `malloc` and free calls are replaced by `tcmalloc` implementation.

But in jemalloc all functions have je_ prefix and it does not replace CRT malloc/free etc with jemalloc functions.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should check your build environment, from the docs: _"By default, the prefix is "", except on OS X, where it is "je__ "."_ here: https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/dev/INSTALL.md

Comment: Don't use malloc in any flavor in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I looked at the code for tcmalloc and they patch the malloc etc (CRT ) functions with their implementation. So any call to malloc/free/new etc from any DLLs loaded by process would use tcmalloc implementation. But jemalloc lacks this patching functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/858592/505088